# How to download entire S3 bucket automatically

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I am able to successfully download all files from aws s3 bucket, so when I click on the particular list item the list item gets download. But, I want all s3 bucket item automatically download when activity is launched.

```
/**
```

* DownloadSelectionActivity displays a list of files in the bucket. Users can
 * select a file to download.
 */
public class DownloadSelectionActivity extends ListActivity {

```
// The S3 client used for getting the list of objects in the bucket
private AmazonS3Client s3;
// An adapter to show the objects
private SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> transferRecordMaps;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_download_selection);
    initData();
    initUI();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Refresh the file list.
    new GetFileListTask().execute();
}

private void initData() {
    // Gets the default S3 client.
    s3 = Util.getS3Client(DownloadSelectionActivity.this);
    transferRecordMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
}

private void initUI() {
    simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, transferRecordMaps,
            R.layout.bucket_item, new String[] {
                    "key"
            },
            new int[] {
                    R.id.key
            });
    simpleAdapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                String textRepresentation) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.key:
                    TextView fileName = (TextView) view;
                    fileName.setText((String) data);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    // When an item is selected, finish the activity and pass back the S3
    // key associated with the object selected
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("key", (String) transferRecordMaps.get(pos).get("key"));
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();


        }
    });

}






/**
 * This async task queries S3 for all files in the given bucket so that they
 * can be displayed on the screen
 */
private class GetFileListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    // The list of objects we find in the S3 bucket
    private List<S3ObjectSummary> s3ObjList;
    // A dialog to let the user know we are retrieving the files
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(DownloadSelectionActivity.this,
                getString(R.string.refreshing),
                getString(R.string.please_wait));
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... inputs) {
        // Queries files in the bucket from S3.
        s3ObjList = s3.listObjects(Constants.BUCKET_NAME).getObjectSummaries();
        transferRecordMaps.clear();
        for (S3ObjectSummary summary : s3ObjList) {
            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("key", summary.getKey());
            transferRecordMaps.add(map);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Suggestion: You should return the Hashmap or list in doInBackground, then that is the parameter to onPostExecute, from which you can update the adapter. That's how an AsyncTask is meant to be used

Answer (score 1):

You already have the list of objects in the bucket, you could just iterate through the list and download each one when the list operation has completed. It might be easier to handle the transfers (allowing pause/resume, checking status, ect...) using the Transfer Utility, which is a high level utility on top of the standard S3 Client.

A guide for the Transfer Utility can be found here (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transferutility.html)

Comment: Thanks...WestonE..but i had already implemented these stuff and Now, I need whole completely automatic..